# Do the animals shown as pieces in the holographic game with Chewbacca and R2D2 on the Millenium Falcon show up in other Star Wars media?

Tags: star-wars, millennium-falcon

The [Dejarik holographic game](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Dejarik) between Chewbacca and R2-D2 shows several different animals. **Do any of those creatures show up in later films, TV series, novels, or video games?**

[image: R2-D2 contemplates his next move]

Here is an image of the board game with names for the pieces. I'm assuming this shows all the pieces.

[image: Dejarik Game Board]

Game piece names:

1. Kintan Strider
2. Mantellian Savrip
3. M'onnok
4. Ghhhk
5. K'lor'slug
6. Houjix
7. Ng'ok
8. Grimtash

Edit to add:

[The Dejarik game](https://www.starwars.com/news/let-the-wookiee-win-dejarik) appears in Star Wars Rebels animated show, but that's the game, not the animals. I am asking about the animals.

Comment: Has anyone ever played the board game? I'd be interested on what folks' impressions are. Looks kinda goofy.

Comment: I'd buy a game board just to get the hologram generator!

Comment: @iMerchant That's not a real game, it's [just a photo print](http://pjmcquade.blogspot.ca/2013/01/star-wars-holochess-at-at-takedown.html) that this artist (PJ McQuade) made, to sell as such.  There is, however, a fan-made Dejarik game using minis from some Star Wars CMG, to be found [here](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/182162/dejarik)  The rules seem pretty basic though ("kill the other guy's dudes") and it uses the monsters' stats from the CMG for combat.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

## Yes, kinda. From a certain point of view.

**Kintan strider**: In *Episode VII: The Force Awakens*, it appeared as pieces of animal (Donderbus blaster ulna handle for Tasu Leech, as per Visual dictionary page 54).

[image]

I haven't been able to find evidence of any other animals in main 7 films or other Disney canon material on Wookieepedia, nor by searching novelization texts.

---

---

**If you include Legends material:**

**K'lor'slug** and some others appeared in *Star Wars: The Old Republic* MPG

**Mantellian Savrip** appeared in a whole bunch of places, including same game (T.O.R.)

(there is a chance some of them also appears in *The New Jedi Order: Agents of Chaos II: Jedi Eclipse* based on what Wookieepedia says, but I don't have access to it today to check).

Comment: Yeah, I saw that, but I’m not sure it really counts as an “appearance.”

Comment: @Adamant - It's true, from a certain point of view.

Comment: @DVK-in-exile According to Wookiepedia, the blaster handle was made from Gunark bones, not a Kintan Strider's bones. http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/%22Huttsplitter%22_blaster_rifle Do you have a citation that show it's made from a strider?

Comment: @RichS - clarified. Gundark bone grip is for his blaster *rifle*, Kintan is for his blaster pistol (Donnderbus)

Comment: Kintans also appear in SWTOR, notably in the _Karagga's Palace_ Operation.

Comment: A lot of them showed up in the SWCCG too, if you include that.

Comment: Mantellian Savrip appears also in the video game Super Star Wars, but called "Kahlar Boss Monster".

Answer (score 15):

### Probably not

Of the various species listed there, only the Mantellian Savrips may have had an appearance in other media. It [may have appeared](https://web.archive.org/web/20161208225433/http://www.starwars.com/news/creatures-of-marvel-star-wars-comics-part-1) in the official Marvel *Star Wars* comic series, in *Showdown on the Smuggler’s Moon, Part III*.

> In Star Wars #10, we also see that Grakkus the Hutt owns a whole
>   menagerie of beasts in cages, including a wampa, a ronto, a brezak
>   (which first appeared in the comics series, The Clone Wars: Slaves of
>   the Republic, written by Henry Gilroy, and then later in The Clone
>   Wars episode 412, “Slaves of the Republic”), as well as a fellow that
>   looks like the Mantellian Savrip from a dejarik game board. There’s
>   also an obligatory tentacle monster, too. Grakkus has almost enough
>   pets from around the galaxy to open his own zoo!

[image]

However, this is not a *Star Wars* show or movie, per se. I can’t find any listed *canonical* appearances for the others, even in non-film media. Outside of canon, and of course definitely not in a TV series or film, some of these creatures can be spotted. The Mantellian Savrips shows up in *Star Wars: The Old Republic: Rise of the Hutt Cartel*, for example.

Comment: Grakkus keeps a wampa? On a hot dry desert world? That's just cruel!

Comment: Why does Jabba appear to have legs in that comic?!?

Comment: @JackAidley that's not Jabba, that's Grakkus, who had a series of cybernetic legs implanted so that he could move about more easily.

Comment: Ord Mantell and its Savrips are part of the base SWTOR game, though some Savrips also appear in the RotHC expansion on Makeb.